# Instantiate the value of an array from one function to a different function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the result of a jquery function attached to an id and change e.g

```
    <script>
$('#dateID').change(function(){
      var bookday = $(this).val();      
      $.post('getDates.php',{postbookday:bookday},
        function(data){ 
          var array = JSON.parse("[" + data + "]");
          var list = []; 
          var newArray = array.flat([2]);
          for (var i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++) {
            list.push(newArray[i]);                 
          }; 

          if (list.length>96) {
            alert("Sorry, day fully booked!");            
          }
          else{
            function selectedTime(list) {                  
            return [a, b, c];
          }
          var result = selectedTime(list);     
          var myArray = [];      
          for (var i=0; i < result[2].length; i++) {
            if (result[2][i] === '09:00') {
              myArray.push(['09:00','10:00']);              
            }
            if (result[2][i] === '10:00') {

              myArray.push(['10:00','11:00']);   

              // here is myArray           

            }
          } 
        }
      });      
    });
</script>
```

and then use it as the input in another different function below:

```
$('#disableTimeRangesExample').timepicker(
  {       
    'disableTimeRanges': myArray 
  }
);
```

How do I get myArray in the next function? considering that it is not static.

Comment: Make it global to those 2 functions so they can both see it

Comment: What timepicker plugin you're using? can you share a link?

Comment: http://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/

Comment: check my updated answer it should give you what you need, I've checked on they website `option` update the disabled times.

Answer (score 3):

You have two options:

#### 1. save the variable in outer scope:

```
var myArray;
$('#selectedDate').change(function(
   ...some computations...
   myArray = [['1pm', '2pm']];
});
$('#disableTimeRangesExample').timepicker({       
  'disableTimeRanges': myArray
});
```

#### 2. save in jQuery data

```
$('#selectedDate').change(function(
   ...some computations...
   $(this).data('array', [['1pm', '2pm']]);
});
$('#disableTimeRangesExample').timepicker({       
  'disableTimeRanges': $('#selectedDate').data('array') || []
});
```

As a side note you will probably also need to update timepicker on each change.

**EDIT**: to update time picker on change of the input you need to put this inside change event:

```
$('#dateID').change(function(){
  var bookday = $(this).val();      
  $.post('getDates.php',{postbookday:bookday},
    function(data){ 
      var array = JSON.parse("[" + data + "]");
      var list = []; 
      var newArray = array.flat([2]);
      for (var i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++) {
        list.push(newArray[i]);                 
      }; 

      if (list.length>96) {
        alert("Sorry, day fully booked!");            
      }
      else{
        function selectedTime(list) {                  
        return [a, b, c];
      }
      var result = selectedTime(list);     
      var myArray = [];      
      for (var i=0; i < result[2].length; i++) {
        if (result[2][i] === '09:00') {
          myArray.push(['09:00','10:00']);              
        }
        if (result[2][i] === '10:00') {

          myArray.push(['10:00','11:00']);   

          // here is myArray           

        }
      }
      $('#disableTimeRangesExample').timepicker(
         'option', {'disableTimeRanges': myArray}
      );
    }
  });      
});
$('#disableTimeRangesExample').timepicker();
```

Comment: Your side note is actually what OP is looking for probably

Comment: So I have edited the code.. myArray is inside an if ... else statement .. I cannot reach it

Comment: @R_M89 if you declerated the variable with var it should be visible in whole function. You should be able to updateh timepicker after your for loop. (but you will need to init the timepicker outside of change event because option only update what's already created).

Comment: so I get the error TypeError: $(...).timepicker is not a function when i put it inside the selectedDate function . Edited a basic frame of the code.

Comment: @R_M89 it mean that you didn't included the plugin or have jQuery NoConflict and/or two version of jQuery. Or you have your main script before timepicker plugin.

Comment: @R_M89 added your latest code, you need to run option of the plugin in same function as your array, so if you have ajax you need to put that in callback.

Comment: I think it is jQuery NoConflict because it loads the example just fine .. How do I resolve it?

Comment: @R_M89 try this `jQuery(function($) { /* your whole code */ });`, if you're loading multiple version of jQuery make sure you have proper order of scripts: jQuery; timepicker; your script+noConflict; next jQuery; other code. Do you have C# MVC or R shiny? those load their own version of jQuery and you should not include one.